# Google Drive API not returning modified time data properly

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm using the GoogleDriveAPI to check the last time a file was modified, if the file has been modified after I last executed the script it should download the file and parse it, otherwise the local version is the latest one.

I'm testint the python script that perform the calls like this:

| HR:M:S | Action | Behaviour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | Update Google Sheet |  |
| 00:00:05 | call script | sees changes and modified time gets updated |
| 00:00:10 | Update Google Sheet |  |
| 00:00:15 | call script | (**DOES NOT SEE CHANGES**) |
| 00:00:50 | call script | (**DOES NOT SEE CHANGES**) last modified time is still 00:00:00 |
| 00:03:00 | Update Google Sheet |  |
| 00:03:05 | call script | (**SEES CHANGES**) |

what it looks like to me is that the Google API groups together changes that occur too close in time.

For reference 05 diff in seconds means instantly (just tabbing to terminal and back to GoogleSheet)

the python script I am using:

```py
 request = service.files().get(fileId='----------------', fields='*')
 value = request.execute()
 file_name = value['name'] + ".xlsx"
 modified_date = value['modifiedTime'].split("T")[0]
 modified_time = value['modifiedTime'].split("T")[1].split(".")[0]


    # some checks


## after some checking with current time, which does not matter, since the 
## value should come from an HTTP request, 
## I still delete the variables where it is stored, both the request return and the values

del value
del modified_date
del modified_time
```

Is this a GoogleDriveAPI issue, or is some part of my code wrong?

something that python is caching maybe?

Or simply behavior from GoogleSheets itself grouping changes as I mentioned?

Is there any way to
Note that the issue is 100% not related to credentials.

Also, the changes are there, if I simply read the document after the call to the API I can see the changes applied a second ago in the version I just downloaded.
But this behaviour of polling is not desired

Comment: value['name'] includes the full file extensions, no need to add value['name'] + ".xlsx"

Comment: NO it does not, in fact to get the "extension" you need value['mimeType'] which returns this for a google sheet: "vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using "Method: revisions.list" of Drive API instead of "Method: files.get" of Drive API? When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

This is a simple sample script for explaining the difference between "Method: files.get" and "Method: revisions.list".

In this script, please use your authorization value of `credentials=creds`.

```py
def updateSheet(sheets, spreadsheetId):
    sheets.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,range="Sheet1",body={"values": [["sample value"]]},valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED").execute()


def getModifiedTimeByDriveFilesGet(drive, fileId):
    res1 = drive.files().get(fileId=fileId, fields="modifiedTime").execute()
    return res1["modifiedTime"]


def getModifiedTimeByDriveRevisionsList(drive, fileId):
    revisions = []
    pageToken = ""
    while pageToken is not None:
        res = drive.revisions().list(fileId=fileId, fields="nextPageToken,revisions(modifiedTime)", pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageToken if pageToken != "" else None).execute()
        r = res.get("revisions", [])
        revisions += r
        pageToken = res.get("nextPageToken")
    return revisions[-1]["modifiedTime"]


def main():
    spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

    sheets = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)
    drive = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)

    n = 5
    for i in range(n):
        print(f"{i + 1}st update sheet")
        updateSheet(sheets, spreadsheetId)
        lastModifiedTime1 = getModifiedTimeByDriveFilesGet(drive, spreadsheetId)
        lastModifiedTime2 = getModifiedTimeByDriveRevisionsList(drive, spreadsheetId)
        print(f"Get modifiedTime by drive.files().get(): {lastModifiedTime1}")
        print(f"Get modifiedTime by drive.revisions().list(): {lastModifiedTime2}")
        time.sleep(5)
```

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
1st update sheet
Get modifiedTime by drive.files().get(): 2023-10-31T03:20:20.268Z
Get modifiedTime by drive.revisions().list(): 2023-10-31T03:22:15.316Z
2st update sheet
Get modifiedTime by drive.files().get(): 2023-10-31T03:20:20.268Z
Get modifiedTime by drive.revisions().list(): 2023-10-31T03:22:22.363Z
3st update sheet
Get modifiedTime by drive.files().get(): 2023-10-31T03:20:20.268Z
Get modifiedTime by drive.revisions().list(): 2023-10-31T03:22:29.379Z
4st update sheet
Get modifiedTime by drive.files().get(): 2023-10-31T03:20:20.268Z
Get modifiedTime by drive.revisions().list(): 2023-10-31T03:22:36.377Z
5st update sheet
Get modifiedTime by drive.files().get(): 2023-10-31T03:20:20.268Z
Get modifiedTime by drive.revisions().list(): 2023-10-31T03:22:43.349Z
```

You can see after the sheet was updated, the value of `drive.files().get()` is not changed from `2023-10-31T03:20:20.268Z`. But, the values of `drive.revisions().list()` are changed every time.

When you retrieve the latest modifiedTime using `drive.revisions().list()`, the last item retrieved from `drive.revisions().list()` is the latest modifiedTime. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get)
- [Method: revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions/list)

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you very much, I sometimes find navigating the GoogleDriveAPI hard

Comment: @Mrmudkip Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.