# Using Python's gspread, can I read the modifiedTime without fetching the entire spreadsheet? I want to use a local cache if there was no change

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm using gspread to load read from my spreadsheets and it's working great. However, I'm hitting Google data caps quite often, especially when I'm testing.

I created a caching method that uses a local copy if it is less than a minute old. However, when debugging, I often have to change things in the spreadsheet and see an immediate change in the execution of the code. On the other hand, because not all calls during debugging need a fresh copy, I'll hit the data caps quickly if I remove the caching.

Is there a way to check if the spreadsheet has changed before fetching it? I know there is a field `modifiedTime` in `_properties` of a spreadhseet, but it doesn't seem to have an accessor method. This suggests to me that there is a mechanism for caching hidden. Is there one.

It also seems to me that to populate `modifiedTime` you need to read the entire spreadsheet anyways. Is that true?

So here is the question: how do I get the last modified time of a spreadhseet without using my data cap? Preferably using only gspread?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, it seems that the property of `modifiedTime` of ["Method: files.get"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get) is not correctly updated by editing cells. [Ref (Author: me)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77393037) So, in this case, ["Method: revisions.list"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions/list) is used for checking the updated time.

In this case, I think that the answer to `It also seems to me that to populate modifiedTime you need to read the entire spreadsheet anyways. Is that true?` is no.

Also, about `So here is the question: how do I get the last modified time of a spreadsheet without using my data cap? Preferably using only gspread?`, I think that googleapis for Python can be used with the client of gspread.

The sample script for checking the last modified time of the Spreadsheet is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
import gspread
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

client = ### # Please set your gspread client.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

drive = build("drive", "v3", credentials=client.auth)
revisions = []
pageToken = ""
while pageToken is not None:
    res = drive.revisions().list(fileId=spreadsheetId, fields="nextPageToken,revisions(modifiedTime)", pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageToken if pageToken != "" else None).execute()
    r = res.get("revisions", [])
    revisions += r
    pageToken = res.get("nextPageToken")
lastModifiedTime = revisions[-1]["modifiedTime"]
print(lastModifiedTime)
```

- When this script is run, the last modified time of the Spreadsheet of `spreadsheetId` is retrieved like `2023-12-21T00:12:34.567Z`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, the last modified time is retrieved by ["Method: revisions.list"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions/list). In order to use this method, [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) is used with the gspread client.

#### Reference:

- ["Method: revisions.list"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions/list)
- Related thread

  - [Google Drive API not returning modified time data properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77389359)